# How to activate application roles using typed dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012-express

I am working in a windows C# 2013 project which has a SQL Server 2012 express database, I have created 3 application roles, I use typed dataset in my project, I search for a way to activate an application role in my project.

I found some information but not complete answers, I made a code but it is not working, because the event *Connection_StateChange* does not fire, here is the code in a class *Class1* in my project i put this code:

```
public string rl, rlPss;
//rl, rlPss are variables contain role name and password.

public void SetAppRole(SqlConnection ta)
{
    if (ta.State==ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ta.Close();
    }
    ta.Open();

    ta.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
}

void Connection_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalState==System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed && e.CurrentState==System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand();
        scm.Connection = (SqlConnection)sender;
        scm.CommandText = "EXEC sp_setAppRole '" + rl + "' , '" + rlPss + "'";
        scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

In login under `btnlogin` I put this code:

```
cl.SetAppRole((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)tableAdapterManager.Connection);

MDIParent1 md = new MDIParent1();
md.Show();
```

I passed role name and password to *rl, rlPss.*

I followed the execution of this code and I found that event *Connection_StateChange* does not get fired.

Comment: The code format really needs improving, Dude.

Comment: I do recommend you to read more about Naming Convention - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

Register the event before you change state

```css
public void SetAppRole(SqlConnection ta   public void SetAppRole(SqlConnection ta)
   {
       ta.StateChange += Connection_StateChange;
       if (ta.State==ConnectionState.Open)
       {
           ta.Close();
       }
       ta.Open();

   }
```